# Using hyphen to avoid repeating a word

Tags: abbreviations, hyphenation

In Finnish, 'linja-auto' is a bus, and 'rekka-auto' is a truck. If I were to write that I traveled with both I would write

> Matkustin linja- ja rekka-autolla.

The sentence is equal to

> Matkustin linja-autolla ja rekka-autolla

so the hyphen (-) can be used to avoid repeating the word 'auto' (meaning *a car*).

Are there similar constructs in English?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the construct has a name in English, but I would submit some examples that work similarly.

- In talking about red blood cells and white blood cells, I would simply say, "red and white blood cells".
- To put forward an example using hyphens, describing a living situation as either on-campus or off-campus (relative to a university, for example) could be summarized as, "on and/or off-campus".

As a note to the last example above, I opted to not include the hyphen when writing out "on" (e.g. "on- and/or off-campus"). Although it may just be a personal preference, I can't think of a particular example that would maintain the hyphen after the split.

Comment: Sulphur- and nitrous-dioxide.  The hyphen makes a difference here.

Comment: The decision to include or leave out the hyphen is often a matter of house style. I've seen universities that do refer to "on- and off-campus housing."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal in English too. Some examples from a quick search:

- [Pre- and post-test probability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-_and_post-test_probability)
- [Pre- and post-workout nutrition for runners](http://www.mensfitness.com/nutrition/what-to-eat/pre-and-post-workout-nutrition-for-runners)
- [how the pro- and anti-Pegida rallies measured up](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/germany/11342953/Germanys-Islamisation-marches-how-the-pro-and-anti-Pegida-rallies-measured-up.html)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to normally-hyphenated phrases, this technique can also be used with words that are normally unhyphenated compounds.  For example, one might write about the "inner- and outermost" parts of something.